# Why am I getting Multiple definition errors while compiling?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, contiki, multiple-definition-error

I'm trying to do a simple program in Contiki to generate a random number between two numbers and then flash it on a Zolertia module.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "contiki.h"
#include <sys/node-id.h>

PROCESS(test_randnum, "Random Number");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&test_randnum);

static struct etimer et;

PROCESS_THREAD(test_randnum, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  int16_t r;

  //random_init(node_id);
  //unsigned short r = random_arnd();

  while(1){

    etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND);

    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));

    r = rand() % (40 - 20) + 20;

    printf("Number: %d\n", r);

    etimer_reset(&et);
    }


  PROCESS_END();
}
```

However when trying to compile the file I get the following "multiple definition" error:

```
user@iot-workshop:~/Desktop/Projeto$ make
using saved target 'zoul'
  CC        test_randnum.c
  CC        ../../contiki//cpu/cc2538/./ieee-addr.c
  CC        ../../contiki//cpu/cc2538/cc2538.lds
  CC        ../../contiki//cpu/cc2538/./startup-gcc.c
  CC        test_randnum.c
  LD        test_randnum.elf
test_randnum.co:(.data.test_randnum+0x0): multiple definition of `test_randnum'
obj_zoul/test_randnum.o:(.data.test_randnum+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../../contiki//cpu/cc2538/Makefile.cc2538:100: recipe for target 'test_randnum.elf' failed
make: *** [test_randnum.elf] Error 1
rm obj_zoul/startup-gcc.o test_randnum.co
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
DEFINES+=PROJECT_CONF_H=\"project-conf.h\"


CONTIKI_PROJECT = test_randnum


CONTIKI_TARGET_SOURCEFILES += test_randnum.c


all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)


CONTIKI = ../../contiki/
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

Already tried to look for a solution but got no results and this is the first time this error is appearing to me.
Does anyone know how to solve this out?

Thank you!

Comment: Q: What source file is the "code" you showed us?  "test_randnum.c", or "something else"? 
 Q: Why don't you declare `test_randnum` (a function?  a variable?) before you use it?  Q: Why does "CC test_randnum.c" appear twice in your "make" output?  Are there two different files (or does make *THINK* there are two different files)?  A complete example (http://www.sscce.org/) would help...

Comment: @paulsm4 yes, the name of the source file is "test_randum.c". Why should I declare `test_randum` as a function or variable? I already edited the question with my Makefile.

Comment: For a "normal C program", you should generally declare every variable and function.  Contiki macros appear to do this for you.  ALSO: Your code + makefile is a perfectly adequate http://www.sscce.org/.  Thank you.  CONCLUSION: the problem is an "ld" link error; the root cause is probably in your Makefile.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) try commenting out `#CONTIKI_TARGET_SOURCEFILES += ...`, 2) Check if you somehow got multiple "test_randnum.o" files anywhere in your build folders, 3) Try to eliminate the double `CC test_randnum.c` output lines from your build.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you very much!! Commeting out `#CONTIKI_TARGET_SOURCEFILES += ...` made it work! Finally! This was a first time for me, I always use that instruction in the Makefile and this was the first time I had problems. Do you have any ideia why it was causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is linker 'ld' error. We can see that the output of make command contains 'CC test_randnum.c' two times which is unusual. It is hard to say without looking into your makefile to suggest some fix.

Comment: I edited the question and added my Makefile